# Running in oil a for light diesel engine (Japanese, Toyota 3L)?

Tags: toyota, oil, diesel, break-in

**What would you use as a running in (break-in) oil for this engine?**

I have this engine, and it has just been reconditioned, new pistons, conrods, crank and bearings.